# Image hover - display title/description UNDER GALLERY section of images (not overlay) - Elementor Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

[image]

Hi all,

Trying to recreate the effect in the above image. Can not fathom a way to display the image title and description underneath the gallery section on hover rather than as an overlay. Tried gallery, flip box and now starting to build out separate images in a block - is there CSS code that will allow this to happen, or is this a JS solution?

I understand it will need adjusting for responsive layouts - that’ll be the ‘wet Wednesday woes’ I’m sure! :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site.  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: you want to change image color after hovering on the image like overlay right?

Comment: I want to change the overlay on hover as well, yes